# Invoke Mercurial without loading global and user configs

Tags: unit-testing, mercurial, configuration-files, rc

I'm writing some unit tests that call out to Mercurial, and I'd like to ensure the tests don't rely on any local state of the machine. I know I can override certain config values, e.g.:

```
hg --config ui.username='Test Account <not-a-real-address@example.com>' ...
```

However this still reads in the global and user `.hgrc` files on the machine, which could affect Mercurial's behavior in an unintended or undesirable way.

Is there a robust way to invoke `hg` without having it look at *any* config files except the `.hg/hgrc` file in the repo? For instance with Bash I can accomplish this with `bash --noprofile --norc`, but I don't see a similar flag for Mercurial.

NB: I'm aware of "heavyweight" options such as running the tests in an isolated virtual environment such as Docker. I'll certainly do something like that if necessary, but I'm wondering if there's a way to configure Mercurial itself.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more poking found [Issue 3147: command line option to disable ~/.hgrc](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3147), which was CLOSED WONTFIX, however the workaround suggested there appears to work as desired:

```
$ HGRCPATH= hg ...
```

This overrides the default search paths for hgrc files, though it isn't mentioned (as of this writing) in the [hgrc docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hgrc.5.html) (edit: it's mentioned on [another page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/environment)).

Example:

```
# lots of inherited config by default
$ hg showconfig | wc
     118     361    7232

$ HGRCPATH= hg showconfig
ui.formatted=True
ui.interactive=False

$ hg init foo && cd foo

$ HGRCPATH= hg showconfig
bundle.mainreporoot=/tmp/foo
ui.formatted=True
ui.interactive=False
```

Comment: dimo414 answer is the good answer. I would add setting `HGPLAIN` also if you plan to read the Mercurial command outputs, this way you will have stable and reproducible outputs.

Comment: @BorisFeld thanks for the suggestion! Not currently a requirement for my use-case, but good to know about.

Answer (score 0):

In scripts you usually want to ensure that no local configuration and localisation breaks it. Mercurial provides the environment variable `HGPLAIN=` for that purpose. Thus in your scripts invoke mercurial always by setting it for that particular invocation of mercurial:

```
HGPLAIN= hg status
```

This makes sure that you see the output as produced by vanilla mercurial. See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/environment and how to define exceptions to this rule, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but `HGPLAIN= hg showconfig` still shows a number of customizations, such as `ui.username`, that I don't want to include. I think `HGRCPATH` is what I need.